# C++ bubble sort function with pointers

Tags: c++, function, pointers, bubble-sort

I'd like to write a program that contains bubble sorting with pointers inside a function.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

void rendez(int* t, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
            if(*t+i<*t+j){
                int temp = *t+i;
                *t+i = *t+j;
                *t+j = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

    int t[10] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

    rendez(&t,sizeof(t)); 

    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

It's giving me these errors:

```
C:\Users\metal\gyakorlás1211.cpp    In function 'void rendez(int*, int)':
C:\Users\metal\gyakorlás1211.cpp    [Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment
C:\Users\metal\gyakorlás1211.cpp    [Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment
C:\Users\metal\gyakorlás1211.cpp    In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\metal\gyakorlás1211.cpp    [Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[10]' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void rendez(int*, int)'
```

Thanks!

Comment: You probably mean `*(t + i)`, etc.  Or just `t[i]`.

Comment: What's wrong with `t[i]`?

Comment: `<iostream>`.  This is C++, not C.

Comment: What is wrong with std::sort?

Comment: I think the question was for `C` language which is edited into `C++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes you need

```
      if(*(t+i)<*(t+j)){
            int temp = *(t+i);
            *(t+i) = *(t+j);
            *(t+j) = temp;
        }
```

And also

```
rendez(t,sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]));
```

Now look what you did earlier, first of all your compiler must have bursted with you lots of warning.

`&t` is `int (*)[10]` which is not what you want in this place.

rather you simply want to pass the array which will eventually decay into pointer and then any changes you do that will reflect to the array.

Earlier your `*t+i` was doing something like this, `(*t)+i` is this what you wanted? And moreover `t` was then `int(*)[10]` so you are basically adding `i` or `j` to it. It was not right. You were working with addresses but you wanted to work with values.

And the second parameter to the function, you wanted to pass the size of the array but not in number of bytes but rather number of elements.

`sizeof (arr)` is basically say `10*sizeof(int)` as it contains `int`. But is this what you want? No. You want to pass the number of `int` elements. So just divided it by size of each `int`. That's what we did in `sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending `&t` in arguments, you're not actually sending the first address of the array, but the address of the whole array.

> **Let's understand this thing**
>   Let's say the array is allocated as **1000, 1004, 1008. . .**
>   so,
>   the address of the first element will be **1000** as when you add 1 in it, it will give you **1004**.
>   and the address of the whole array will be **1000** as when you add 1 in it, it will give the next address of the last element in the array.

`t` is the pointer to the first element and `&t` is the pointer to the array.
So to pass the array to the other function just send `t` in the argument.

Now, `sizeof` operator does not return the length of the array, but the size it allocated.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c) and write your function call as.

`rendez(t, sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]));`

---

**Now about the `lvalue` error.**

`*` has higher priority than `+` so `*` executes first.
So writing like this `*t + i` will give you the ith next address from the first element of the array.
So you need to write like 
`*(t + i)` in assignment operation.

Answer (score 0):

This call

```
rendez(&t,sizeof(t));
```

is wrong because the expression `&t` has type `int (*)[10]` instead of the type `int *` that is the type of the first parameter of the function `rendez`.

You should call the function like

```
rendez( t, sizeof(t) / sizeof( *t ) );
```

And the second parameter of the function should have type `size_t`.

also within the function this if statement

```
        if(*t+i<*t+j){
            int temp = *t+i;
            *t+i = *t+j;
            *t+j = temp;
        }
```

is also wrong.

It must to look like

```
        if( *( t + i ) < *( t + j ) ){
            int temp = *( t + i );
            *( t + i ) = *( t + j );
            *( t + j ) = temp;
        }
```

Take into account that the bubble sort algorithm compares adjacent elements.

Your function implementation looks like an inefficient selection sort.

If you want to use only pointers then the function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

void rendez( int *a, int n )
{
    for ( int *first = a, *swapped = a, *last = a + n; !( last - first < 2 ); first = a, last = swapped )
    {
        swapped = a;
        while ( ++first != last )
        {
            if ( *( first - 1 ) < *first )
            {
                swapped = first;
                int tmp = *first;
                *first = *( first - 1 );
                *( first - 1 ) = tmp;
            }
        }
    }        
}


int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    rendez( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
```

The function indeed implements the bubble sort algorithm.